# Catching the integer value changes on view

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, model-view-controller

```
<th scope="col" style="vertical-align:middle" >MS</th>
        
<td style="font-size:12px;vertical-align:middle";><b>@home_score-@away_score</b></td>
```

I tried some Jquery for solve this problem but while page refleshing i get the alert...

My question is this
The partial view refleshing every 5 seconds but some values are stable
How can i catch the changed values
If i catch it i want to play some sounds...

Comment: i have a a variable like number 3 paging refleshing and the result same : 3 but it might be change to 4 if it changes i need to some js calls..

Comment: How are the values being changed?  You should hook into that process, either with a callback or a custom-event.

Comment: i have a variable and i need listen it the values changing. Values cames from the model in view and i need to listen to them with using jscript or jquery